# Sharing of conn pointer between interfaces in golang

Tags: go

What I'm trying to accomplish is sharing a pointer of db.sqlx between multiple functions, except for posts saying pass along the pointer, which is fine but how to do that in an interface?  I cannot find anything that illustrates the use of this anywhere.  Basically what I have is an interface of type Datastore.  I also have mysql & pgsql that implements the Datastore type.  The interface by itself works fine however the issue is I'm trying to create a single connect function for *sqlx.DB to be shared across all functions within the implemented interface.  I think the issue is I've confused myself on how to share the pointer between functions of the interface or even "where" to share it.  The main interface looks like below:

```
var (
    storage Datastore
    db * sqlx.DB
)

type Datastore interface {
    Insert(db *sqlx.DB, table string, item DataItem) bool
    CheckEmpty(db *sqlx.DB, table string) bool
    FetchAll(db *sqlx.DB, table string) []DataItem
    DBInit(db *sqlx.DB)
    initDB()
}
```

Within my implemented interface (simplified mysql example) I have the initDB function which looks like this:

```
type MySQLDB struct {
    config *config.Configuration
}


func (my *MySQLDB) initDB() {
    log.Println("Getting DB Connection")
    tempdb, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", my.config.Database.Dsn+"&parseTime=True")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    db = tempdb
    defer db.Close()
}

func (my *MySQLDB) FetchAll(db *sqlx.DB, table string) []DataItem {
    dTable := []DataItem{}
    query := "SELECT foo, bar FROM " + table + " ORDER BY last_update ASC"
    err := db.Select(&dTable, query)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    return dTable
}
```

At this point I know the connection is initially opened but the next time a function is called I get db is closed error.  So how do I properly share the db connection between functions, or do I really have to run a connection open in every function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call **defer db.Close()** in your **initDB** function. After that function executed, db will close too! So when you call your method you get the closed error.
Maybe you need to re-desgin your interface, for example:

```
type Datastore interface {
    Insert(table string, item DataItem) bool
    CheckEmpty(table string) bool
    FetchAll(table string) []DataItem
    Close() error // call this method when you want to close the connection
    initDB()
}
```

Your **MySQLDB** implement now look like:

```
type MySQLDB struct {
    config *config.Configuration
    db *sqlx.DB
}


func (my *MySQLDB) initDB() {
    log.Println("Getting DB Connection")
    tempdb, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", my.config.Database.Dsn+"&parseTime=True")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    my.db = tempdb
}

func (my *MySQLDB) Close() error {
    return my.db.Close()
}

func (my *MySQLDB) FetchAll(table string) []DataItem {
    dTable := []DataItem{}
    query := "SELECT foo, bar FROM " + table + " ORDER BY last_update ASC"
    err := my.db.Select(&dTable, query)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    return dTable
}
```

Comment: In `Close`, was that supposed to be `my.db.Close()`?